# Is $P(A\cap B \mid C) = P(A \mid C) \cap P(B \mid C)$ correct?

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I'm new at Statistics and I was wondering some problem. Suppose you have two independent events $A$ and $B$ and you want to calculate the conditioned probability of having either $A$ or $B$ if you have $C$, that is: 
$P(A\cap B  \mid  C)$

Is this correct: $$P(A\cap B  \mid  C) = P(A \mid  C) \cap P(B  \mid  C)\,\,?$$

Thanks a lot!

Comment: That is not true (a) because probabilities are real numbers so you do not intersect them and (b) having $A$ and $B$ independent overall does not imply they are conditionally independent given another event

Comment: Do you instead mean $P(A\cap B|C) = P(A|C) \cdot P(B|C)$?

Comment: @Dasherman, it is $P(A\cap B\mid C)= P(A\mid(B\cap C)) P(B\mid C)$.